# Bottom navigation bar animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, navigationbar

I want to make it so that when you click on one of the icons, a certain strip appears under it, which will mean that the person is on this page (something like this)

[image]

At the moment, my navbar looks like this

[image]

Here's what I have at the moment (HTML):

```js
let marker = document.querySelector('#marker');
let item = document.querySelectorAll('nav a .MuiSvgIcon-root');

function indicator(e) {
  marker.style.left = e.offsetLeft + "px";
  marker.style.width = e.offsetWidth + "px";

}
item.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    indicator(e.target)
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  z-index: 100;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-root {
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1.4);
   :hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}

#marker {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0;
  background: #000;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="marker"></div>

<HomeIcon/>

<TimelineIcon/>

<AccountCircleIcon/>

<ExploreIcon/>
```

`.MuiSvgIcon-root`  there is defining all icons.

Comment: Where's this element? `'nav a .MuiSvgIcon-root'`

Comment: Typo :)
Need to be like this:
let item = document.querySelectorAll('.MuiSvgIcon-root');

Comment: In your html, there's not element with that class

Comment: .MuiSvgIcon-root in React and Material icons is like defining all icons.

Comment: You can add a class to every Icon, and then just change .MuiSvgIcon-root to your class(if it will be easier for you).

Comment: In that case, please add `reactjs` tag in your question for it to be visible to more appropriate section in SO

Comment: Ok, I will do it

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is correct. You should check your HTML and CSS. Because their structure is important

Comment: What do you think in HTML and CSS is not correct?

Comment: I don't know. i can't run this code snippet. Does your console have any error messages? The simplest way to implement the tab bar is like this.

Comment: That is the problem, that console log doesn`t show me any errors. Just nothing!

Comment: Make sure you can trigger the click event first.

Comment: Ok, will try with trigger

Comment: Take a look.[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-meadow-hw76j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: THANK A LOT! WORKS!